# Demux 1 LED at a time

Tags: arduino-uno, c++, multiplexer

I have the 14051 Demux set up with an Arduino Uno R3 and I am able to light up all three LED's at once with a 1 second delay however, I want to light up 1 LED at a time how can I do this?

> My Hardware Setup

[image: My Hardware Setup]

> Sketch

```
/*  Arduino sketch   */

int64_t wait= 1000;
void setup() 
{
  pinMode(7,OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(7,LOW);
  DDRB = 0b00000111;  //PORT 8,9,10 as output
  PORTB = 0b00000000; //PORT 8,9,10 set to LOW
}

void loop() 
{
  PORTB=0b00000000; //Data falow - X0
  uint8_t Sensor0 =  analogRead(A0); //read data from X0
  delay(wait);

  PORTB=0b00000001;  //Data flow - X1
  uint8_t Sensor1 =  analogRead(A0); //read data from X1
  delay(wait);

  PORTB=0b00000010;  //Data flow - X2
  uint8_t Sensor2 =  analogRead(A0); //read data from X2
  delay(wait);

  digitalWrite(7,HIGH);  // Inhibit / stop all data
  delay(wait);  
  digitalWrite(7,LOW);  // Inhibit /  let data flow
}
```

Comment: How would analogRead(A0) be able to feed current to the selected LED? Looks like a lot of cut-and-paste-programming?

Comment: The answer is the same as the one to [your other question](http://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/34559/demultiplexing-arduino-with-c-code), which to me looks like a duplicate. Anyway you should not read the data from the analog pin, but rather `digitalWrite(A0, HIGH);`

Comment: @frarugi87 Can you post an example of this code implemented with the sketch I posted.

Comment: @MALKAVIAN in the setup write `pinMode(A0, OUTPUT); digitalWrite(A0, HIGH);` and in the loop remove all the lines with the `analogRead` (the A0 pin is already high from the setup)